# need a shell script in the output of Jenkins log if a value doesn't match jenkins job should fail

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Can anyone help me how to write a shell script logic if the value doesn't greater than the output of the presenting value in the console log Jenkins job should fail?

suggest me if any Jenkins plugin available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a value in the console log to trigger a build failure then you can use this plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

You write regex's to trigger info, warn or errors. You can combine this with a shell build step to assess a parameter e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Shell build step'
if [ ${yourParameter}  == "true" ]; then
    echo 'Your text to check with the log parser plugin to trigger a fail'
fi
```

And then configure your job to use a plugin rule that looks for the text:

```
'Your text to check with the log parser plugin to trigger a fail'
```

The plugin supports regex's, so it's quite powerful, I've used it a lot.